# BeautifulSoup encoded characters cannot be decoded

Tags: python, encoding, beautifulsoup

I am following some instructions form a video and I seem to have a hit a brickwall.
When running my script across the following website i am trying to access the containter that hosts the odds for each game in order to import thme into a separate csv file.

```py
import bs4
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

#my_url = 'https://www.google.com/search?q=premier+league&rlz=1C1GCEU_en-GBIN877FR877&oq=pre&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j69i57j35i39j69i65l2j69i60l3.628j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#sie=lg;/g/11fj6snmjm;2;/m/02_tc;mt;fp;1;;'
my_url = 'https://sports.coral.co.uk/sport/football/matches/tomorrow'

uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

container = page_soup.find_all("div",{"class":"oddsicard desktop-sport-card"})
print(len(container))
```

However, I run into the issue that i cannot select to the container as all of the characters are not readable. I have tried this on other pages and it seems to work, so i figure its something wrong with the decoding or the webpage itself.

When printing this is the output:

```
vn#���b��
��
�u��W��!�JE�O���;�����
��7�_�,p ��AGh��}���oP�.ܱy;o/��-�{A��rrsh|?[Z����
I�N��]����l�b՜��f6�='��.���R�NWex����&amp;���Q�����m0��~�c�N���zA#/
```

If anyone could help that would be much appreciated.

Comment: server may send page compressed with `gzip` or `br` and you have to uncompress it on your own. Probably using module `requests` you would get it uncompressed. Or you may try to use `header` in `request` to send information that you `accept` only `flat` data. [Accept-Encoding](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept-Encoding)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This url sends data compressed with [brotli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brotli) and it won't to send it uncompressed when I tried to use header `'Accept-Encoding'` with other compressions.

You have to install module [brotlipy](https://pypi.org/project/brotlipy/) and use it to decompress content

```
import brotli

page_html = brotli.decompress(page_html)
```

---

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq

my_url = 'https://sports.coral.co.uk/sport/football/matches/tomorrow'

uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

print(uClient.headers['Content-Encoding']) # `br` means `brotli`

import brotli

page_html = brotli.decompress(page_html)

print(page_html)
```